# Permissions group users exist but not displayed

Tags: permissions, groups, missing

I have several users added to a group permissions. I can see their names if I roll the cursor over check boxes, but otherwise, their names are not displayed. Anyone know why this would happen?

[image]

Comment: I guess some custom CSS classes are applied to your page. because of that the names are not visible. check if there is any custom CSS added.

Answer (score 0):

Use google chrome developer console tool and see what css attributes are being applied on any one row. I think of below possibilities.

- Color of your front text is same as background(white or gray based on alternate row)
- text are being hidden due to css attributes and displays only when on hover.
- check for any css customization being done.

Definitely it has something to do with css attribute where text is getting hidden.

Comment: Thanks! I do have a <span style="display: none">. I'm not too keen on how to override a <span style> in Sharepoint. Any ideas?

Comment: it is OOTB view right? I think there would be some javascript which would be running to make span as display:none...

Comment: check for any customization.

Comment: I found it. I had it set to display: none for .ms-tableCell .ms-verticalAlignTop. Thanks!

Comment: Please upvote and mark it as answer for other's reference...